# Reset document indentation in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, indentation

Using PyCharm v5 I run into an issue with indentation when pasting code into an existing document. In the settings, I've set all PyCharm files to have 4 spaces of indentation but when I paste code the document changes to what that code is using (2 in this case). How can I reset the document indentation?

Comment: You can do: `ctlr` + `shift` + `A` (or `cmd` on Mac), and then type: `To Spaces`.

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference. Why can't I just set the indentation of a specific document?

Comment: Well, you can do it in Sublime, if you use it.

Comment: Yeah I use it. Its just a bit annoying that a simple feature like that isn't available in PyCharm.